# Visual Basic looping controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, foreach

I have a web application that I'm writing. I have a lot of buttons, all named the same thing except with a number appended (button1,button2,button3...etc.). All of these are in a panel named Panel3. I would like to loop through these blank ImageButtons and set their image using .ImageUrl. I know my getIconImage() function works.

```
    Dim cntrl As Control
    For Each cntrl In Me.Panel3.Controls

        cntrl.ImageUrl = getIconImage(4)

    Next
```

**The problem is** "cntrl" does not recognize .ImageUrl as an option. It is like it doesn't recognize itself as an ImageButton.
I am using asp.net and vb.net. Thanks!

(as a note: I have also tried "Me.Controls" with no such luck. Also, I have tried setting a temporary ImageButton object equal to "cntrl" and modifying the .ImageUrl from there.)

Comment: Where are you looping thru controls?  OnLoad event?  [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.85).aspx) Also you might want to edit your question with an update of what is the problem you are trying to solved.

Comment: I have attempted an array of ImageButtons with asp/vb.net, but it is much more difficult and messes with my web page design. I'm attempting this method because I believe it to be the easiest.

Comment: I am looping through at Page_Load, yes. I will fix my question, thank you!

Comment: `Ctype(cntrl,ImageButton).ImageUrl = getIconImage(4)` or change the loop indexer to `As ImageButton` and loop thru `Controls.OfType(Of ImageButton)`

Comment: I've attempted your first solution already with no luck. I could not try your second solution exactly because .OfType was not an available option. I did try searching for each imgButton in Me.Controls like you suggested, but I got an error saying: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton'".

Comment: I apologize Plutonix. It appears I did have "ofType", I just had to force it a little bit (it didn't appear in dropdown). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
For Each cntrl As ImageButton In Me.Panel3.Controls.OfType(Of ImageButton)
```

May have to do `Imports System.Linq`

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what the issue is so i'll assume you need to check which type of control you are getting in the loop:

```
 Dim cntrl As Control
 For Each cntrl In Me.Panel3.Controls
    if TypeOf cntrl Is ImageButton Then 
       cntrl.ImageUrl = getIconImage(4)
    End if
 Next
```

Comment: I'm sorry. In order to clarify, the problem is "cntrl" does not recognize .ImageUrl as an option. It is like it doesn't recognize itself as an ImageButton. I have tried your "if" check before and it doesn't fix my problem. There are only ImageButtons in "Panel3".